# Passing data to PHP from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following code in ajax. I am passing two parameters, `$job_id` and `q` to a page called interview.php but. However, that page gives me a warning that `$job_id` is undefined. I am not sure how to POST or GET more then one variable using AJAX.

My ajax file is:

```
<script>
function showSuccess ($getid,str) {
  var job_id= $getid;
var resp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    resp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var data = "job_id="+job_id
     xmlhttp.open("POST", 
      "interview.php?q="+str); 
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
     xmlhttp.send(data);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =
  function display_data() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
     } else {
        alert('Request not successful.');
      }
     }
  }


</script>
```

interview.php:

```
<?php 
$q = intval($_POST['q']);
?>
<?php 

$getid = $_POST['job_id'];?>

<?php
include('includes/conn.php');

$row="SELECT  idNo,id,name,jobTitle,SUM(points) AS total FROM shortlist WHERE job='$getid' GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT $q";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $row['name'];
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `var job_id= $getid;` is it works??

Comment: The script that runs is 'else {
        alert('Request not successful.');
      }'.After clicking OK on the alert box,I get a warning that q is undefined index

Comment: try this ....   data:{para1:value1,para2:value2}

Comment: Why does `interview.php` close and reopen PHP so much? If you find yourself writing `?><?php`, something is probably wrong somewhere.

Comment: care also for security with mysqli_query. You inject $getid and $q witout checking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t understand javascript and ajax, just try to use something simple like jQuery.

You actually give just one variable to the PHP script, and this is reason you get this error. Try to change this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "interview.php?q="+str);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "interview.php?q="+str+"&job_id="+job_id);
```

Comment: also if you want to do it with pure js read and learn this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

change your `data` to this `var data = "job_id="+job_id+"&q"+str`.
`Undefined index: q` is because of your are using `post` method to get data and you are sending data with `get` method that's why you get error.
try below code.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","interview.php"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: and mind one thing this `var job_id= $getid;` will not assign any value to your `job_id`. :)